# Laravel push get all changes from model and relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I update a model with the method `save()`, I can get all changes with the `boot` function `saving`. You only get the changes on de model that you save.

I use `push()` to save multiple relationships simultaneously. But how can I get all changes that it makes? Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Digging into base Model shows all methods `save`, `boot` and `push` return boolean or void (which means you can't return the model instance via them). Could you please share some code to understand exactly what you mean?

Comment: @user8555937 I'm using this `$business->push();` for updating model and relationships. I wanne check if something was change and what has change.

Comment: `push` calls `save` on each relationship tied to that model. `push` does not return what changes have been made to the model and relationships. You'll have to create a custom function to check for that.

Comment: So i must change the `push` and `save` functions?

Comment: Yes, that would be your best choice. Dig into `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and extend them in your model class.